# Hybris types of promotions and rule based promotion

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions, hybris-data-hub

Hybris has several types of "basic" promotions like :

- ProductPerfectPartnerPromotion
- ProductBundlePromotion
- AcceleratorProductBOGOFPromotion
- AcceleratorProductMultiBuyPromotion
- ProductPercentageDiscountPromotion
- OrderThresholdDiscountPromotion

This promotions are simple to configure and understand, however I don't understand the last promotion the hybris OOTB has: RuleBasedPromotion.

What is the diference between the "basics" promotions mentioned before and the rule based promotions?

Also, what is a Promotion Rule Source ? I've see that you can add to a promotion group several promotion rule source.

Comment: Why is this tagged drools?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Listed Promotions are legacy promotions and some them are compatible with new rule-based promotions.

**Why above classes are still present in hybris?**

To maximize backward compatibility, the new Promotion Engine provides an implementation of the Promotion service. This allows promotion results to be written by the new Promotion Engine and read by the existing application that calls the Promotion service such as the Accelerator.

This implementation retains the Promotions (Legacy) in your project. Promotion Engine overrides certain Spring beans. Promotions (Legacy) items continue to exist but should be unused.

You can easily migrate to rule-based promotion from legacy promotion.
Please follow this link:
[promo_migration](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2011/en-US/38c9225b471140fdac52cae62b3eebfa.html)